# use character string in R inside SQL WHERE IN statement having issues with LIKE statement

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a query similar like the one below where I need to use a string of characters and it works okay but not when I use the LIKE statement. Please read further below

```
ids
 [1] "0000000000000000010000001" "0000000000000000010000002" "0000000000000000010000003"
 [4] "0000000000000000010000004" "0000000000000000010000005" "0000000000000000010000006"
 [7] "0000000000000000010000007" "0000000000000000010000008" "0000000000000000010000009"
[10] "0000000000000000010000010"


expr1 <- sprintf("select
 FSAS.a_id,
 FSAS.grade,
 FSAS.score,
 FSAS.placement,
 FSAS.start,
 FSAS.completion 
 FROM db.Fact AS FSAS
   WHERE FSAS.a_id IN (%s)", paste0(sQuote(ids, q = FALSE), collapse=", "))

sqlQuery(con, expr1)
```

So above code works but code below does not when I add the LIKE statement. I want to find all placements that begins in FR hence why using LIKE 'FR%' but I think it is interferring with the IN statement. The error I am getting is 'too few arguments'. How could I correct this issue please?

```
ids
 [1] "0000000000000000010000001" "0000000000000000010000002" "0000000000000000010000003"
 [4] "0000000000000000010000004" "0000000000000000010000005" "0000000000000000010000006"
 [7] "0000000000000000010000007" "0000000000000000010000008" "0000000000000000010000009"
[10] "0000000000000000010000010"

expr1 <- sprintf("select
 FSAS.a_id,
 FSAS.grade,
 FSAS.score,
 FSAS.placement,
 FSAS.start,
 FSAS.completion 
 FROM db.Fact AS FSAS
   WHERE FSAS.a_id IN (%s) and FSAS.placement LIKE 'FR%'", paste0(sQuote(ids, q = FALSE), collapse=", "))

sqlQuery(con, expr1)
```

Comment: are you sure that SELECT * FROM db.Fact AS FSAS WHERE FSAS.placement LIKE 'FR%' `has any rows that fit

Comment: @nbk yes. When I put LIKE 'FR001', I get one of the answer I need. But there are several other FR.

Comment: both parts of the where clause have to be true to show a result, so if the id of FR001 is not in the in clause, you don't receive an answer, so do a query like i posted and check if at least one row has the id in the in clause

Comment: @nbk yes it has. I ran the query in the SQL interface and not R and it works too. I think issue is coming with paste0 where it is also taking 'FR%' as something to paste in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a literal % in a sprintf format string double it.  Also toString can be useful here.

```
s <- "select
 FSAS.a_id,
 FSAS.grade,
 FSAS.score,
 FSAS.placement,
 FSAS.start,
 FSAS.completion 
 FROM db.Fact AS FSAS
   WHERE FSAS.a_id IN (%s) and FSAS.placement LIKE 'FR%%'"

sprintf(s, toString(sQuote(ids, FALSE)))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!! One more thing, do you have any idea how I can force this query to display empty rows as NULL? Right now it is just blank

Comment: Don't understand question.  Can you create a reproducible example with input, output and expected output.